# Maximum of How many textures can be drawn inside 4 vertex data

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

I have two squares with six vertex as in the image. I want to add texture to them I want to add same texture about 30 times between two squares in metal [image] is it Possible ? To my understanding I could able to add two textures
Is it possible add about 30 times same textures between two square

Comment: To be clear, do you just want to tile one texture horizontally along the x-axis of the quadrilateral created by these triangles, or do you want to apply multiple distinct textures?

Comment: @warrenm i want to add a same texture multiple times inside two quadrilateral . Like Texture Brushes in Drawing Apps

Comment: @warrenm I will explain my need. this is a line created by four triangles. i want to add a texture with in this 4 triangles which should appear as a brush. https://imgur.com/a/tfKhxly. I hope the brush feeling can be achieved by  tiling one texture over x axis as well

Comment: You can write the fragment shader however you like. It can sample from many different textures (up to 31 on iOS, 128 on macOS). It can sample multiple times at multiple positions of a single texture. Either way, you would blend the results.

Comment: @KenThomases What is the method used for sampling Textures in fragment shader 31 times in iOS